# Zero being returned instead of empty string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with a query:

```
USE SCRUMAPI2

DECLARE @userParam VARCHAR(100)
    ,@startDateParam DATETIME
    ,@endDateParam DATETIME
    ,@orgTeamPK VARCHAR(100)
    ,@teamId VARCHAR(100)
    ,@productId VARCHAR(100)
    ,@search VARCHAR(200)

SET @userParam = 'David Tunnell (tunnelld)'
SET @startDateParam = '2013-10-21 00:00:00'
SET @endDateParam = '2013-10-27 23:59:59'
SET @orgTeamPK = '%'
SET @teamId = '%'
SET @productId = '%'
SET @search = '%%'

SELECT RowType AS RowType
    ,Person AS Person
    ,Project AS Project
    ,ProjectType AS ProjectType
    ,StoryNumber AS StoryNumber
    ,StoryTitle AS StoryTitle
    ,Effort AS Effort
    ,Task AS Task
    ,OriginalEstimateHours AS OriginalEstimateHours
    ,MondayHours AS Monday
    ,TuesdayHours AS Tuesday
    ,WednesdayHours AS Wednesday
    ,ThursdayHours AS Thursday
    ,FridayHours AS Friday
    ,SaturdayHours AS Saturday
    ,SundayHours AS Sunday
    ,TotalHours AS Total
FROM (
    -- DATE DISPLAY
    SELECT '1' AS RowType
        ,'' AS Person
        ,'' AS Project
        ,'Category' AS ProjectType
        ,'Incident #' AS StoryNumber
        ,'' AS StoryTitle
        ,'' AS Effort
        ,'' AS Task
        ,'' AS OriginalEstimateHours
        ,'' AS Category
        ,'' AS IncidentNumber
        ,'' AS ApplicationName
        ,(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d, @startDateParam, @endDateParam) >= 7 THEN '' WHEN DATEDIFF(d, @startDateParam, @endDateParam) <= 5 THEN '' WHEN DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(DAY, 0, @startDateParam)) = 2 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, 0, @startDateParam), 111) ELSE '' END) AS MondayHours
        ,(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d, @startDateParam, @endDateParam) >= 7 THEN '' WHEN DATEDIFF(d, @startDateParam, @endDateParam) <= 5 THEN '' WHEN DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(DAY, 1, @startDateParam)) = 3 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, 1, @startDateParam), 111) ELSE '' END) AS TuesdayHours
        ,(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d, @startDateParam, @endDateParam) >= 7 THEN '' WHEN DATEDIFF(d, @startDateParam, @endDateParam) <= 5 THEN '' WHEN DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(DAY, 2, @startDateParam)) = 4 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, 2, @startDateParam), 111) ELSE '' END) AS WednesdayHours
        ,(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d, @startDateParam, @endDateParam) >= 7 THEN '' WHEN DATEDIFF(d, @startDateParam, @endDateParam) <= 5 THEN '' WHEN DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(DAY, 3, @startDateParam)) = 5 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, 3, @startDateParam), 111) ELSE '' END) AS ThursdayHours
        ,(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d, @startDateParam, @endDateParam) >= 7 THEN '' WHEN DATEDIFF(d, @startDateParam, @endDateParam) <= 5 THEN '' WHEN DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(DAY, 4, @startDateParam)) = 6 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, 4, @startDateParam), 111) ELSE '' END) AS FridayHours
        ,(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d, @startDateParam, @endDateParam) >= 7 THEN '' WHEN DATEDIFF(d, @startDateParam, @endDateParam) <= 5 THEN '' WHEN DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(DAY, 5, @startDateParam)) = 7 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, 5, @startDateParam), 111) ELSE '' END) AS SaturdayHours
        ,(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d, @startDateParam, @endDateParam) >= 7 THEN '' WHEN DATEDIFF(d, @startDateParam, @endDateParam) <= 5 THEN '' WHEN DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(DAY, 6, @startDateParam)) = 1 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, 6, @startDateParam), 111) ELSE '' END) AS SundayHours
        ,'' AS TotalHours
    --

    UNION ALL

    --
    -- GRAND TOTALS
    --
    SELECT '2' AS RowType
        ,'All Personnel' AS Person
        ,'' AS Project
        ,'' AS ProjectType
        ,'' AS StoryNumber
        ,'' AS StoryTitle
        ,'' AS Effort
        ,'Total:' AS Task
        ,'' AS OriginalEstimateHours
        ,'' AS Category
        ,'' AS IncidentNumber
        ,'' AS ApplicationName
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 2 THEN DTH.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS Monday
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 3 THEN DTH.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS Tuesday
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 4 THEN DTH.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS Wednesday
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 5 THEN DTH.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS Thursday
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 6 THEN DTH.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS Friday
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 7 THEN DTH.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS Saturday
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 1 THEN DTH.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS Sunday
        ,CAST(SUM(DTH.[Hours]) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS Total
    FROM DailyTaskHours DTH
    LEFT JOIN Task TSK ON DTH.TaskId = TSK.PK_Task
    LEFT JOIN Story STY ON TSK.StoryId = STY.PK_Story
    LEFT JOIN NonScrumStory NSS ON DTH.NonScrumStoryId = NSS.PK_NonScrumStory
    LEFT JOIN Sprint SPT ON STY.SprintId = SPT.PK_Sprint
    LEFT JOIN Product PDT ON STY.ProductId = PDT.PK_Product
    LEFT JOIN ProductTeamUser PTU ON TSK.ProductTeamUserId = PTU.PK_ProductTeamUser
    LEFT JOIN [User] USR ON PTU.UserId = USR.PK_User
    LEFT JOIN OrganizationalTeam OLT ON USR.OrganizationalTeamId = OLT.PK_OrganizationalTeam
    LEFT JOIN UserAuthorization UAN ON (
            PDT.PK_Product = UAN.ProductId
            AND USR.OrganizationalTeamId = UAN.OrganizationalTeamId
            AND UAN.Deleted IS NULL
            )
    WHERE DTH.PointPerson LIKE @userParam
        AND ActivityDate >= @startDateParam
        AND ActivityDate <= @endDateParam
        AND COALESCE(OLT.PK_OrganizationalTeam, '') LIKE @orgTeamPK
        AND (
            COALESCE(UAN.ProductId, '') LIKE @productId
            OR COALESCE(UAN.OrganizationalTeamId, '') LIKE @teamId
            )
        AND (
            (
                STY.Number LIKE @search
                OR STY.Number IS NULL
                )
            OR (
                STY.Title LIKE @search
                OR STY.Number IS NULL
                )
            OR (
                TSK.NAME LIKE @search
                OR STY.Number IS NULL
                )
            )

    UNION ALL

    --
    -- Details by PERSON, PROJECT, SPRINT, STORY, TASK
    --
    SELECT '3' AS RowType
        ,DTH.PointPerson AS Person
        ,COALESCE(PDT.[Name], APP.AppName) AS Project
        ,(
            CASE WHEN (
                        STY.KanBanProductId IS NOT NULL
                        AND STY.SprintId IS NULL
                        ) THEN 'KanBan' WHEN (
                        STY.KanBanProductId IS NULL
                        AND STY.SprintId IS NOT NULL
                        ) THEN 'Sprint' ELSE SCY.Catagory END
            ) AS ProjectType
        ,COALESCE(STY.[Number], NSS.IncidentNumber) AS StoryNumber
        ,COALESCE(STY.Title, NSS.[Description]) AS StoryTitle
        ,STY.Effort AS Effort
        ,COALESCE(TSK.[Name], '') AS Task
        ,TSK.OriginalEstimateHours AS OriginalEstimateHours
        ,SCY.Catagory AS Category
        ,NSS.IncidentNumber AS IncidentNumber
        ,APP.AppName AS ApplicationName
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 2 THEN DTH.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS MondayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 3 THEN DTH.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS TuesdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 4 THEN DTH.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS WednesdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 5 THEN DTH.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS ThursdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 6 THEN DTH.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS FridayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 7 THEN DTH.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS SaturdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 1 THEN DTH.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS SundayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(DTH.[Hours]) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS TotalHours
    FROM DailyTaskHours DTH
    LEFT JOIN Task TSK ON DTH.TaskId = TSK.PK_Task
    LEFT JOIN Story STY ON TSK.StoryId = STY.PK_Story
    LEFT JOIN NonScrumStory NSS ON DTH.NonScrumStoryId = NSS.PK_NonScrumStory
    LEFT JOIN SupportCatagory SCY ON NSS.CatagoryId = SCY.PK_SupportCatagory
    LEFT JOIN [Application] APP ON NSS.ApplicationId = APP.PK_Application
    LEFT JOIN Sprint SPT ON STY.SprintId = SPT.PK_Sprint
    LEFT JOIN Product PDT ON STY.ProductId = PDT.PK_Product
    LEFT JOIN ProductTeamUser PTU ON TSK.ProductTeamUserId = PTU.PK_ProductTeamUser
    LEFT JOIN [User] USR ON PTU.UserId = USR.PK_User
    LEFT JOIN OrganizationalTeam OLT ON USR.OrganizationalTeamId = OLT.PK_OrganizationalTeam
    LEFT JOIN UserAuthorization UAN ON (
            PDT.PK_Product = UAN.ProductId
            AND USR.OrganizationalTeamId = UAN.OrganizationalTeamId
            AND UAN.Deleted IS NULL
            )
    WHERE DTH.PointPerson LIKE @userParam
        AND ActivityDate >= @startDateParam
        AND ActivityDate <= @endDateParam
        AND COALESCE(OLT.PK_OrganizationalTeam, '') LIKE @orgTeamPK
        AND (
            COALESCE(UAN.ProductId, '') LIKE @productId
            OR COALESCE(UAN.OrganizationalTeamId, '') LIKE @teamId
            )
        AND (
            (
                STY.Number LIKE @search
                OR STY.Number IS NULL
                )
            OR (
                STY.Title LIKE @search
                OR STY.Number IS NULL
                )
            OR (
                TSK.NAME LIKE @search
                OR STY.Number IS NULL
                )
            )
    GROUP BY DTH.PointPerson
        ,PDT.[Name]
        ,SPT.[Name]
        ,SPT.[Description]
        ,STY.[Number]
        ,STY.Title
        ,TSK.[Name]
        ,SCY.Catagory
        ,NSS.IncidentNumber
        ,APP.AppName
        ,STY.KanBanProductId
        ,STY.SprintId
        ,NSS.[Description]
        ,TSK.OriginalEstimateHours
        ,STY.Effort
    HAVING SUM(DTH.[Hours]) > 0
    --

    UNION ALL

    --
    -- Sub-TOTAL by PERSON
    --
    SELECT '4' AS RowType
        ,DTH.PointPerson AS Person
        ,'' AS Project
        ,'' AS ProjectType
        ,'' AS StoryNumber
        ,'' AS StoryTitle
        ,'' AS Effort
        ,'Subtotal:' AS Task
        ,'' AS OriginalEstimateHours
        ,'' AS Category
        ,'' AS IncidentNumber
        ,'' AS ApplicationName
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 2 THEN DTH.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS MondayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 3 THEN DTH.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS TuesdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 4 THEN DTH.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS WednesdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 5 THEN DTH.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS ThursdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 6 THEN DTH.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS FridayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 7 THEN DTH.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS SaturdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 1 THEN DTH.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS SundayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(DTH.[Hours]) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS TotalHours
    FROM DailyTaskHours DTH
    LEFT JOIN Task TSK ON DTH.TaskId = TSK.PK_Task
    LEFT JOIN Story STY ON TSK.StoryId = STY.PK_Story
    LEFT JOIN NonScrumStory NSS ON DTH.NonScrumStoryId = NSS.PK_NonScrumStory
    LEFT JOIN SupportCatagory SCY ON NSS.CatagoryId = SCY.PK_SupportCatagory
    LEFT JOIN [Application] APP ON NSS.ApplicationId = APP.PK_Application
    LEFT JOIN Sprint SPT ON STY.SprintId = SPT.PK_Sprint
    LEFT JOIN Product PDT ON STY.ProductId = PDT.PK_Product
    LEFT JOIN ProductTeamUser PTU ON TSK.ProductTeamUserId = PTU.PK_ProductTeamUser
    LEFT JOIN [User] USR ON PTU.UserId = USR.PK_User
    LEFT JOIN OrganizationalTeam OLT ON USR.OrganizationalTeamId = OLT.PK_OrganizationalTeam
    LEFT JOIN UserAuthorization UAN ON (
            PDT.PK_Product = UAN.ProductId
            AND USR.OrganizationalTeamId = UAN.OrganizationalTeamId
            AND UAN.Deleted IS NULL
            )
    WHERE DTH.PointPerson LIKE @userParam
        AND ActivityDate >= @startDateParam
        AND ActivityDate <= @endDateParam
        AND COALESCE(OLT.PK_OrganizationalTeam, '') LIKE @orgTeamPK
        AND (
            COALESCE(UAN.ProductId, '') LIKE @productId
            OR COALESCE(UAN.OrganizationalTeamId, '') LIKE @teamId
            )
        AND (
            (
                STY.Number LIKE @search
                OR STY.Number IS NULL
                )
            OR (
                STY.Title LIKE @search
                OR STY.Number IS NULL
                )
            OR (
                TSK.NAME LIKE @search
                OR STY.Number IS NULL
                )
            )
    GROUP BY DTH.PointPerson
    HAVING SUM(DTH.[Hours]) > 0
    ) AS My_View
ORDER BY Person
    ,RowType
    ,Project
    ,ProjectType
    ,StoryNumber
    ,StoryTitle
    ,Task
```

And this is what is being returned:
[image]

I have Effort and OriginalEstimateHours set to be empty but 0 is returning. How can I make the cells blank?

Comment: What is the type of Effort and OriginalEstimateHours? I guess numbers of some sort and they're not allowed to be empty? You may want to return a bogus number, like -99 to show it's actually "false"

Comment: The query you've posted doesn't match the result set you're showing. Where have `Category`, `IncidentNumber` etc gone to? And `MondayHours` has become `Monday`

Comment: Their types are INT and BIGINT, this is likely why this is occuring. But I would like it empty anyway.

Comment: I'm only showing part of the query, it's actually about 300 lines long.

Comment: Well, the part of the query that's responsible for changing `''` into `0` isn't the part you've shown - so we can't help you locate the issue.

Comment: I have updated the post with the entire query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that `STY.Effort` and `TSK.OriginalEstimateHours` (in the `SELECT` clause for rows of `RowType` 3) are numeric.

From the documentation for [`UNION`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx):

> The definitions of the columns that are part of a UNION operation do not have to be the same, but they must be compatible through implicit conversion. **When data types differ, the resulting data type is determined based on the rules for [data type precedence](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx).**

(**My emphasis**)

Wrap those columns in `CONVERT(varchar(20),STY.Effort)` so that the type chosen for those columns is `varchar` rather than a numeric type.

Answer (score 2):

> Their types are INT and BIGINT,

If you want an empty string, and not `0` or `NULL`, you will need to use the `CAST` or `CONVERT` functions to cast the column to a varchar type. You can't put an empty string in a number column. You may also need to then use a `CASE` statement to tranform a `0` string into an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign empty string, depends on the datatype, it is converted to a different value. 0 for integer, 1900-01-01 for date, etc. Refer this for more information
http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/70/posts/10841/empty-string-and-default-values.aspx